# Reactjs push route after dispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux

Hello I am having trouble finding where I can call a route with push after authenticating the user

I did it using redux

my action:

```
const AuthenticateUser = (login, password) => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch (startAuth ());
        // fetching data
        api.post ('/ login', {login, password})
            .then (response => {
            localStorage.setItem ('token', response.data [0]);
            dispatch (userAuthenticated (response.data [1]))
        })
            .catch (err => {console.error (err);});
    }
}

export default AuthenticateUser;
```

my reducer:

```
const authReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case USER_AUTHENTICATED:
            return {
                ... state,
                loading: false,
                authenticated: true,
                user: action.user,
            }
        case USER_FAILED_AUTH:
            return {
                ... state,
                loading: false,
                message: action.error

            }
        default:
        return state;
    }
}
```

and my form

```
const SignIn = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [login, setLogin] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    dispatch(auth(login, password))
  }
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>

      <Grid container spacing={2} className={classes.gridMain}>

        <Grid item lg={12} md={12} sm={12} xs={12} align="center">
          <img src={require("../nodejs-icon.svg")} alt="bug" height={100} />
        </Grid>

        <Grid item lg={12} md={12} sm={12} xs={12} className={classes.TextField}>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <TextField
              className={classes.input2}
              id="demo2"
              label="Usuário"
              variant="outlined"
              value={login}
              onChange={(e) => setLogin(e.target.value)}
              InputLabelProps={{
                classes: {
                  root: classes.label,
                  focused: classes.focusedLabel,
                  error: classes.erroredLabel
                }
              }}
              InputProps={{
                classes: {
                  root: classes.cssOutlinedInput,
                  focused: classes.cssFocused,
                  notchedOutline: classes.notchedOutline,
                },
                startAdornment: (
                  <InputAdornment position="start">
                    <PersonSharpIcon style={{ fontSize: 25, color: 'rgba(20, 176, 12,0.9)' }} />
                  </InputAdornment>
                )
              }}
            />
            <TextField
              className={classes.txtFd}
              id="demo2"
              label="Senha"
              variant="outlined"
              value={password}
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
              InputLabelProps={{
                classes: {
                  root: classes.label,
                  focused: classes.focusedLabel,
                  error: classes.erroredLabel
                }
              }}
              InputProps={{
                classes: {
                  root: classes.cssOutlinedInput,
                  focused: classes.cssFocused,
                  notchedOutline: classes.notchedOutline,
                },
                startAdornment: (
                  <InputAdornment position="start">
                    <LockSharpIcon style={{ fontSize: 25, color: 'rgba(20, 176, 12,0.9)' }} />
                  </InputAdornment>
                )
              }}
            />
            <ButtonBase variant="raised" disableFocusRipple="false" disableRipple="false" centerRipple="false">
              <Typography noWrap className={classes.labelForgot} variant="subtitle2">
                Esqueci minha senha
          </Typography>
            </ButtonBase>
            <Button type="submit" className={classes.button} variant="raised" disableFocusRipple="false" disableRipple="false" centerRipple="false">
              Entrar
        </Button>
          </form>
        </Grid>
```

I have a route and after I authenticate this user I wanted to send it to a route or display an error msg, but I don't know where in the code to do it and how I would get it.

my route

```
const AppRouter = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
          <Route path="/xd" component={AuthPage} exact={true} /> 
          <Route path="/dashboard/addProduct" component={AddProduct} exact={true} /> 

  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Comment: Why you don't pass the `push` function as an argument in your AuthenticateUser function(you can use camelCase for this function since it's not a component authenticateUser) ? and call it over there if the request succeeds? I'm assuming you're using react router so if you're using it you can use the withRouter wrapper to get it in your component and then pass it in.

Comment: Yes i'm using a router browser i edited the answer with it

could you help me how would i do this?

Comment: In your `SignIn` component you need to import this `import { withRouter } from "react-router";` after that you wrap your component for example like this `export default withRouter(SignIn);` and you will have in the props of the SignIn component  the `history` prop which comes from the router and contains the `push` function, after that you can use that prop in your `handleSubmit` something like this `dispatch(auth(login, password, push))`

Comment: and on my function i make this signin: const SignIn = (props) => {

Comment: i make this and my function sign in have push undefinied                                        i give console.log on props and got this: / history: {length: 2, action: "POP", location: {…}, createHref: ƒ, push: ƒ, …}
location: {pathname: "/xd", search: "", hash: "", state: undefined}
match: {path: "/xd", url: "/xd", isExact: true, params: {…}}
staticContext: undefined

Comment: You may use `useEffect` in `SignIn` component, which checks for flag `authenticated: true (which is passed via props)` and does the redirection.

Comment: @sardok u can post one reply with this bro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is in order to give you an answer that is readable instead of using the comments.
In your `SignIn` component:

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
const SignIn = (props) => {
 const { history } = props;
 const { push } = history;
 // more variables
 const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  // You pass the push function over here.
  dispatch(auth(login, password, push))
 }
// Rest of the logic
}
export default withRouter(SignIn);
```

The withRouter would give you all the props that are coming from react-router, this will allow you to use the history object, which contains the push function, to redirect the user to the page you want.

Then in your authenticate function which I'm guessing is the ´AuthenticateUser´ function you could do this:

```
const AuthenticateUser = (login, password, push) => {
return dispatch => {
    dispatch (startAuth ());
    // fetching data
    api.post ('/ login', {login, password})
        .then (response => {
        localStorage.setItem ('token', response.data [0]);
        dispatch (userAuthenticated (response.data [1]))
        // push goes here
        push("/your-awesome-route")
    })
        .catch (err => {console.error (err);});
}
}

export default AuthenticateUser;
```

Comment: Does this work on vanilla redux or does it need any middleware?

Comment: I believe the user in the question is using `redux-thunk` not sure tbh but it should work on any middleware, or without it, I do this all the times using ´redux-saga´ for example

Comment: @Jean
could you just ask me one more route question?

Comment: sure what is it? @MykonSpt

Comment: i have a structure in my router browser

where i have mine
<header>
<navbar>
<switch>
here I put all my content routes
</switch>
<footer>

but I would need two routes that didn't display my navbar header
footer

but I can't do it

here my pastebin: https://pastebin.com/Eiu53dk7

Comment: What do you mean by that? I don't understand you, you want to have two pages that don't show either the header and the footer?

Comment: Yes, this

I set my header and footer in my route file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59293847/react-router-show-only-route-without-components-defined-in-my-browser if u can help m e

Answer (score 0):

You may use `useEffect` in `SignIn` component, which checks for flag `authenticated: true` (where this variable is passed via props) and does the redirection.

Something like that

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const { authenticated, navigation } = props;
    if (authenticated) {
        navigation.navigate(Routes.GoodPlace);
    }

  });
```

Comment: first i need pick state with useSelector?

Comment: `mapStateToProps` should pass it to the `SignIn` component.